# Regex - change commas only in a portion of a string

Tags: regex, string, replace

I make a lot of changes on a original csv string. there is a lot of comma delimiter. I have to replace by a ";" either only the commas inside the expression || ....|| or only the commas outside this expression. i need to do this change in order to have different delimiter in the expression ||....|| compare to the rest of the string.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/W2Q02N/2):

```js
(.*)(?:\|\|)(?:.*)(,)(?:.*)\|\|
```

After I use

```js
var regex = /myregex/g;
var str = str.replace(regex, ',')
```

thanks

Comment: You want to match all occurrences of `\|{2}.*?\|{2}` and inside the matches, you want to replace all commas with `;`?

Comment: i just want to replace all commas in occurence or replace all other comma outside occurence

Comment: Its quite a long pattern, but with lookbehinds the get the comma inside the `||` you might use https://regex101.com/r/bGuWJz/1 and to get the comma's outside of the `||` https://regex101.com/r/XJR26j/1

Comment: superb. it's a long and very complex pattern. thanks a lot
do you use some app to help you ?

Comment: @gandolfi Mostly I use https://regex101.com/ to test the pattern. Is may seem overwhelming due to the length, but there are repeating parts in the pattern that make it long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const string = "aba,bjlj,alj,ljlj||name1,name2,name3||jflkj,glfgjlf,jflg,fjlfd||name1,name2||fd,sdfsfd,dfs||name1,name2,name3,name4,name5||";
console.log( string.replace(/\|{2}[\w\W]*?\|{2}/g, (x) => x.replace(/,/g, ';')) );
```

The regex is

```js
/\|{2}.*?\|{2}/gs      // matches any text between two double pipes
/\|{2}[\w\W]*?\|{2}/g  // matches any text between two double pipes
/\|{2}.*?\|{2}/g       // matches any text but line breaks between two double pipes
```

Note the `.` does not match line breaks without the `s` modifier flag.

The regex matches double pipe, then any zero or more chars, as few as possible up to the next double pipe.

Then, `x`, the whole match value, is passed as an argument to the anonymous callback function used as a replacement argument, and all commas are replaced with `;` only inside the matches.

The **"contrary"** solution is to match and capture the strings between double pipes and only match commas in all other contexts so that you could keep the captures and replace those commas:

```js
const string = "aba,bjlj,alj,ljlj||name1,name2,name3||jflkj,glfgjlf,jflg,fjlfd||name1,name2||fd,sdfsfd,dfs||name1,name2,name3,name4,name5||";
console.log( string.replace(/(\|{2}[\w\W]*?\|{2})|,/g, (x,y) => y || ';') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Big Thanks.

I also find

```js
var newStr = str.replace(/\|{2}.*?\|{2}/g, function(match) {
 return match.replace(/,/g,";");
});
```

- Do you think is it possible to do the contrary and change all the comma outside the occurence ||...|| ?

Comment: The solution is identical to mine but does not match any chars between double pipes. Please consider removing it, and I will add a "contrary" solution to my answer.